# Finding all the solutions to $x=py+qx$ and $y=px+qy$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How do you find all the solutions to the simultaneous equations?
> $$x=py+qx \\ y=px+qy$$

I see $x=0,y=0$ as solutions.

But what about the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your system as
\begin{align}
   0 =(q-1)x+p y\\
   0=p x+(q-1)y
\end{align}
If $p=q-1$ then you have, in effect, just one equation and there are infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy it. In fact, as Lutz Lehmann points out, $|p|=|q-1|$ make the equations linearly dependent and, thus, there are infinitely many pairs that satisfy them. When $|p|\ne|q-1|$, the only solution is $x=0, y=0$.

Comment: It is more general, the determinant is zero if $|p|=|q−1|$.

Comment: You're right. The determinant is $(q-1)^2-p^2$. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

There should be infinite solutions unless there are bounds for $p$ and $q$.

If we add the equations together, we obtain: $$x+y=(x+y)(p+q)$$
Dividing both sides by $x+y$ (assuming $x\neq -y$), we get
$$p+q=1$$
If we set $p=q=0.5$, as long as $x=y$, it works. Therefore, there are infinite solutions.

Comment: You should simultaneously also consider the difference of the equations $$x-y=(q-p)(x-y),$$ this gives a second case for non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I see with these types of questions, it can be easy to miss solutions. Is there anyway to be reasonable certain that you have all the solutions? And what do you mean by non-trivial solutions?

Comment: The zero solution is the trivial one for a homogeneous system. For it to have more solution you need the determinant to be zero. This here is similar to an eigenvalue problem.